# Why i'm getting [object Object] using sessionStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `sessionStorage` but why i'm getting `[object Object]` in console:-

[image]

Jquery Code:-

```
$('#accordionParent').on('click', '[value="Save"]', function () {
            $('#accordion .panel').hide();
            var openCollapse = $(this);
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('setCollapse', openCollapse)
        })

        if (sessionStorage.getItem('setCollapse') !== null) {
            getCollapse.parents('.panel').show();
        }
```

I want to show collapse using `sessionStorage` simply its working fine but i have to show collapse after refresh page so i'm using `sessionStorage`.

Where i'm wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Because it stores only strings.

Comment: `openCollapse` is a jquery object containing a DOM element. You can't store DOM elements in session storage. What are you really trying to save?

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: Given that a DOM element exists only on your current page, there is no point in storing it in a storage whose only purpose is to live past the page.

Comment: you are trying to save an object into session storage but it only saves string. If you really want to save that object then you should stringify the object and store it.. hope this helps :)